# Change language DURING SETUP

Tags: macos

I reinstalled macOS and my device will be employed by the Apple DEP program. For a documentation I need screenshots of this process in English. However currently my device will only show me the setup in German. When I delete the NVRAM and go to recovery mode I can select a language and when chosing English, the recovery mode menu will be in English. However when I reinstall macOS and the setup appears, it's in German again...
I tried changing it with the the terminal command during the setup, but for

```
languagesetup
```

I need root rights or sudo, which doesn't work since I haven't setup a root password and can't manage to change it....

So does anybody have a quick tip, how to change the language of the setup?

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't mentioned how (which way) you are using to reset the NVRAM (there are several ways) I am post the solution which I know that works.

These instructions is from Apple, to reset NVRAM/PRAM.

I had already a similar situation like yours, and I could solve with this procedure.

> Shut down your Mac, then turn it on and immediately press and hold
>   these four keys together: Option, Command, P, and R. You can release
>   the keys after about 20 seconds, during which your Mac might appear to
>   restart.

Note: you will have to keep those keys pressed during the reset for at least 20 seconds, **until it auto-resets again at least 2 times**, only after the second time it resets and show the apple logo for the second time is when you can release those keys.

Reference procedure is from Apple. 
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Comment: This actually helped me, thanks!